# How to pass a parameter to image onclick event in c# MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a param to the image onclick event. I know how to do it using a script and the controller, but I would like to know if it can be done directly in the view ? I've searched the SO and tried some examples but nothing worked so far.

```
@{string test = "kkkk";}
<img onclick="alert('' + @test + '')" />
<img onclick="alert(@test)" />

@{string test = "alert('kkkk')";}
<img onclick="alert(@test)" />
```

Comment: You are missing the `'` around your vars... for example `<img onclick="alert('@test')" />`, this treats it as a string, otherwise its looking for a javascript object with that name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an alert with kkkk

```
  </span>@{string test = "kkkk";}
    <img onclick="alert('@test')" />
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add details that support your answer? Its not clear what is wrong with the OP code none the less why your solution would work...

Answer (score 2):

this works perfect

```
@{string test = "kkkk";}

<img src="" onclick="alert('@test')" />
```

as @Çöđěxěŕ mentioned, here is the update:
The reason why this solution works, op has not used single quotation marks around the var @test.